# Mac desktop connect to IOS devices

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Does the apple provide any framework or library for Mac desktop that let me find or connect to IOS devices?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Which kind of connection are you talking about? Do you mean a USB connection or a network connection?

Comment: both. Do you have any ideas? even using c core library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not provide anything formal.  Under the covers is the private MobileDeviceAccess.framework.

Take a look at https://bitbucket.org/tristero/mobiledeviceaccess - that puts Objective-C helpers around a bunch of the functionality.

Comment: Hi Jeff Laing, Is there any library for mac, having kind of notification to get, if any ios device gets connected or disconnected to the mac? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at https://bitbucket.org/tristero/ipodaccessframework - that puts Cocoa wrappers around the mobiledeviceaccess library and gives you the ability to register an event listener that gets called back when an IOS device is connected or disconnected.  Its a little more overkill in that it assumes you want to display a window as well.